# device.getCurrentPackagename is returning as null in espresso test case

Tags: android-espresso

Here is my test method

```
@Test
    public void testLeadChangeStageToUnqualifiedReason() throws InterruptedException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> leadData = LeadData.simpleLead();
        lead.createLead(leadData);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        LeadPage.waitForLandingPage();
        lead.changeStage("Unqualified","Not interested");
        onView(withText("Lead stage changed")).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
                    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
            device.wait(Until.findObject(By.res(device.getCurrentPackageName(), "lead_stage_txt")), 7000);
            stage = device.findObject(By.res(device.getCurrentPackageName(), "lead_stage_txt")).getText();
        CommonHelpers.tapLandingBackButton();
        CommonHelpers.tapHomeScreenButton();
        Assert.assertEquals("Stage name differed", stage,"Unqualified");
    }
```

so after validating the toast message , I am trying to get a text of a element using UIObject , Unfortunately I am getting `device.getCurrentPackageName()` as Null which result in exception

I also tried with  `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().getRootInActiveWindow();` that also returns Null

Can anyone help on this issue

Getting root node as null

the above also didn't work
when I am calling device.findObject
I am getting rootNode as null

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo getRootNode() {
        final int maxRetry = 6;
        long waitInterval = 250;
        AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = null;
        for (int x = 0; x < maxRetry; x++) {
            rootNode = mUiAutomatorBridge.getRootInActiveWindow();
            if (rootNode != null) {
                return rootNode;
            }
            if (x < maxRetry - 1) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Got null root node from accessibility - Retrying...");
                SystemClock.sleep(waitInterval);
                waitInterval *= 2;
            }
        }
        return rootNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName()`?

You can also have this in a const variable which can be reused across tests.

```
private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_NAME =
            InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName();
```

Also for accessing strings in the app, you can use the same context instead of having to enter them manually
For e.g,

```
sampleString=InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getString(R.string.sample)
mDevice.findObject(By.desc(sampleString)).click();
```

Comment: still getting  AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootNode(); as null